# sonata_type_collection changing tab on validation

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata

i have a problem on validation:

i have an admin ( scuolaAdmin) with sonata_type_model in a tab:

```
->tab('docenti')
->add('docentiScuole','sonata_type_collection',array('error_bubbling' => true,'by_reference' => false , 'required' => false, 'label' => $dictionary->getLemma("aggiungiDocente") ), array( 'edit' => 'inline','inline' => 'table'))
->end()
```

the admin docentiScuoleAdmin has a validation

```
public function validate(ErrorElement $errorElement, $object)
{
    $errorElement
        ->with('docenti')
            ->assertLength(array('max' =>10))
        ->end()
    ;
}
```

everythings works but if the validation fails, the correct text is displayed under docenti field, but the page doesn't show the correct tab ('docenti')
but it show the first tab

there is a way to display the correct tab? 
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonataAdminBundle embebed form validation error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35925712/sonataadminbundle-embebed-form-validation-error)

Comment: I think this is a missing feature of SonataAdmin. You might do this with Javascript (if there is an error, change to tab with error). Would be nice if you could add a PR for this on github.